# UIlabel text appear in wrong place using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a custom cell and text label. I set auto layout property like following:
[image]

Label text obviously should appear in label frame, that you can see in storyboard. However, when i run app i see following:

[image]

Another bug, when i select row text label again change frame:

[image]

How to fix that with auto layout?

UPDATE: Now i change cell property like that: [image]

Still, for some reason left horizontal constraint not work:
[image]

Comment: Are you setting the image into the default cell image view instead of your custom image view?

Comment: No, i definetely use ImageView for custom cell class -     [cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:news.standardImage]];

Comment: And does a layout run happen when the image has been loaded from the URL?

Comment: I guess when the image has been downloaded and set it invalidates its intrinsic content size and the UI updates, you see the image... Something else isn't working. Either the constraint is removed, or there's an ambiguity and its ignored, or something isn't set when the layout runs. You need to check the log and debug

Comment: Have you tried using some stack views ?

Comment: @DogCoffee no. Actually, when i set bottom constraint to UIImageView, first screenshot does not appear anymore, it always appear like on second screen. But still, constraint (horizontal) between image view and text label not work, dont know why.

Comment: Add the constraints of label like below
1)Leading space to superView instead of Image
2)Remove fixed width constraints

Comment: where is your answer @evgeniy

Comment: @evgeniy : fixed the label width & remove leading space .It may work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. If anyone curious, that was following:

XCode add some property to UILabel called textLabel, and i named my property textLabel as well. So, instead of using my property i set text to default text label, which is left aligned..